# Orchard 1.9.1 Duplicating Menu

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I just upgraded an Orchard website from 1.7.1 to 1.9.1 and it seems like a number of things were broken in the process. I managed to fix all of them except for one - all of my navigation items in the menu lost the links to their associated content items, so when I started adding them back in for some reason the front-end start duplicating everything. I'm on a custom theme and the menu started showing up properly, but it's duplicating all menu items right in the root with `<option />` tags. I can hide those through CSS easily enough, but it's also adding "undefined" in here too, something I can't seem to target and hide.

[image: Bad Site Navigation]

Any idea why this is happening?

**Update** I figured out the "undefined" part - it's more of the content menu items being blown out, but this time it was a custom link (just a #, since it didn't go anywhere) that didn't have a URL, so it was showing as undefined. The rogue `<option />` values are still here, though I can hide them via CSS. I just don't like that they are in the markup at all.